# Is it possible to comment out a line of mixed syntax code (PHP + HTML) with a single keybind?

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

When I comment out a line of strictly PHP code using my keybind (ctrl+/), the entire line is commented out and becomes grey in color, as desired.  The same is true for a line of strictly HTML code.  But if execute the same keybind on a line that is a mix of HTML and PHP code, e.g.

```
<img width="<alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $spacious_slider_title ); ?>">
```

the entire line does not become grey in color.  Only the HTML portions of the line become grey ([screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVNpb.jpg)).  Plus, in that case, I believe the PHP code will still execute.  Is there a way to completely comment out a line of mixed syntax code like this, ensure the PHP code does not execute, and have the line completely greyed out in VS Code, with a single keystroke?  If so, how would I approach that?

My current course of action in these cases is to carry out the comment keybind, which wraps the line in HTML comments.  After, I will manually add a `//` before the PHP code to also comment it out.  I'm hoping there is a single keybind solution to this, as this sometimes becomes tedious.

I should perhaps note that I just installed VS Code and am learning it.  I am coming from SublimeText, so the first thing I did was install SublimeText keybinds. This was an issue with SublimText as well, and I don't believe there was a solution.

I've seen this previous question ([How to comment out both HTML and PHP in PHP inside HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26334348/how-to-comment-out-both-html-and-php-in-php-inside-html)).  While it is related, it doesn't exactly answer my particular question about a VS Code keybind.

Comment: FWIW, this works for me in PhpStorm, you end up with this: `<!--<img width="<alt="--><?php //echo esc_attr( $spacious_slider_title ); ?><!--">-->` Would you consider switching? ;)

Comment: @Davіd not the OP but I too am facing the above issue and I would absolutely switch to PhpStorm (I used to use before), if it had a community edition as it does with IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @Script47 Ah, 'tis true, that's such a pity. It's a really great IDE, but very expensive :(

Comment: @Davіd At this point, since I'm just now getting into the swing of things with VS Code (after a migration from SublimeText), I probably wouldn't be interested in switching to PHP Storm.  But if VS Code presents me with more challenges like this, I may consider it.

Comment: @Davіd I know what you mean. But, to be honest, PhpStorm is actually cheaper than Netflix.